# installing 100 amp sub panel with overgauge wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I want to provide power from my existing 200 amp service to an outbuilding 300 feet away that used to have metered 200 amp service. The account was closed and the transformer removed by the previous owner. The existing wire and poles look in good condition and I have a new panel in the outbuilding. Any issues I should be aware of and what gauge wire to connect the 25 foot run to these poles?   ty

Comment: In your title you say "overgauge wire", by which I believe you mean over sized, but you never specify what size wire. In your question, you only ask about what size wire to use to connect to the pole, but don't tell what's on the pole. You say the wire _looks_ to be in good condition, but don't give us any pictures for those more experienced to chime in. Please [edit] to provide some more details so you can get a better quality answer.

Comment: Where is your meter located with regards to the origin of the pole run in question?  I take it we're talking about a 3-wire overhead run here for that matter? Last but not least, and most importantly, *who is your electric utility*?? We need to know the last because the wires are likely *theirs*, and it's rather...unusual for most utilities to transfer installed plant to the customer

Comment: I read the question wrong to start, first the load would need to be known and utility service wires are much smaller than the feeder you would use (note the transformer removed was at least 12kv in most areas that is stepped down allowing for much smaller wires to be used.

Comment: The major questions are: Where was the transformer located? & Who owns the poles and wires? The latter is usually but not always the utility. If the transformer was located at the building, even if you DO own the poles and wires, you'll need different wires. If the transformer was at the end near your source building **AND** you own the poles and wires **THEN** we'd need details about what those wires are, and how many of them there are (probably one less than you need for a subpanel, unless you buy two transformers.) If the utility owns the poles and wires, don't even think about using them.

Comment: ...and if the usual situation applies, (Utility owns the poles and wires) the simple solution is to have them restore service.